# How to get the new line break if there are some in the text area

Tags: javascript, html

I have textarea and i want, when i post the form if there are any new lines in the text area to get them and output the text with them, like the wysiwyg editors does.

What can't you understand

I have form and i want to get te text area value on post SO IF THERE ARE NEW LINES IN THE VALUE OF THE TEXT AREA I WANT WHEN I OUTPUT THE TEXT THAT THE FORM GETED THOSE NEW LINES TO BE DISPLAYED AS ACTUALY NEW LINES LIKE THE WYSIWYG EDITORS>

Comment: I'm having difficulties understanding your English/question?!?

Comment: I'm having also trouble to understand you question.

Comment: Yes - please update it again, can't understand.

Comment: :) I think your caps lock is broken!

Comment: Don't yell, don't just repeat. Make the question clear, and give an example if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line breaks are interpreted as `\n`.

With javascript you can use regular expression to detect the new line character.

regex:

```
/\n/
```

**UPDATE:**

```
var newStr = "String with line breaks".replace(/\n/g,"<br />");
```

this will replace the new line in textarea with `<br>` tag to make a new line

Comment: no man i want to output the new line not to text area.If i have some new lines in the text area and when i post some form or whatever i want those lines to be outputed to

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression in JavaScript to search for new line character `RegExp("\n")`.